# Can I block access to a particular IP address on my network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I'd like to block access to the ip address associated with my router. I have the `etc/hosts` file and a pi hole, but neither one of those will work because it's the ip address that I want to block. I'd like to make it so that no user on the network can edit the router settings.

I'm considering whether I might be able to do this with little snitch instead. How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like there's a related thread specific to Macs, but it's five years out of date https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154374/how-to-edit-the-hosts-to-block-ip-address

Comment: For clarification: Are you trying to block devices from connecting to your router? Doing so may prevent those devices from accessing the internet. Have you tried setting a password on your router instead?

Comment: That's a great idea, that's exactly what I'm going to do. Thanks